# My CustomAuthorizationPolicy.Evaluate() method never fires

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, authorization

I create a wcf service with custom authorize and authentication as you can see:

```
public class AuthorizationPolicy : IAuthorizationPolicy
{
    string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string Id
    {
        get { return this.id; }
    }

    public System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimSet Issuer
    {
        get { return System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimSet.System; }
    }

    // this method gets called after the authentication stage
    public bool Evaluate(EvaluationContext evaluationContext, ref object state)
    {
        // get the authenticated client identity
        IIdentity client = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

        // set the custom principal
        evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] = new CustomPrincipal(client);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"d:\a.txt", client.Name);

        return true;
    }
}
public class CustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    private IIdentity _identity;
    public IIdentity Identity
    {
        get
        {
            return _identity;
        }
    }

    public CustomPrincipal(IIdentity identity)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"d:\a.txt", identity.Name);
        _identity = identity;
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"d:\a.txt", role);
        return false;
    }
}
```

With this webconfig:

And

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<client />

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceAuthorization
        serviceAuthorizationManagerType  
    ="wcfrestauth.RestAuthorizationManager, wcfrestauth"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpServiceBehavior">
      <!-- Important this is the behavior that makes a normal WCF service to REST based service-->
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="wcfrestauth.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WCFRestAuthentication/api/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="wcfrestauth.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpServiceBehavior" />
  </service>
</services>

<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https"/>

</protocolMapping>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And

```
[OperationContract]
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Admin")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/Data/{data}")]

string GetData(string data);
```

But my Evaluate function never fired. Why?

Comment: Should I change anything in webconfig?

Comment: As a note i use webhttpbinding